# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, listview

Why am I getting the error `Input string was not in a correct format`. in this line of my code?

```
Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Items[4].SubItems[4].ToString())
```

Below is the full code I am using it with:

```
foreach (ListViewItem iiii in listView1.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Items[4].SubItems[4].ToString()) <= Convert.ToInt32(tenthousand.ToString()))
    {
        message2 = "GREAT";
        msgColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        break;   // no need to check any more items - we have a match!
    }

    labelVideoViews2.Text = message2;
    labelVideoViews2.ForeColor = msgColor2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) method will throw this exception when you pass to it a sting which is not a number.

This exception will be thrown if the value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9). So make sure that the string value `listView1.Items[4].SubItems[4].ToString()` is a valid number and contains only digits from 0-9 and an optional sign at the beginning.

Alternatively you could use the [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method which will not throw an exception:

```
int result;
if (int.tryParse(listView1.Items[4].SubItems[4].ToString(), out result))
{
    // the value was successfully parsed to an integer => use the result variable here
}
else
{
   // the supplied value was not a valid number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely your string contains a character other than `int` like letter or even dot

before doing convert debug your app and make sure that is actually only number

```
listView1.Items[4].SubItems[4].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need convert integer to string and parse it back:

```
Convert.ToInt32(tenthousand.ToString())
```

Also you are enumerating over all items, but using only forth one `listView1.Items[4]`. I think this is by mistake. And use `Int32.TryParse` to avoid parsing exceptions:

```
foreach (ListViewItem iiii in listView1.Items)
{
     int value;
     string text = iiii.SubItems[4].ToString();
     if (!Int32.TryParse(text, out value))
     {
         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Cannot parse text '{0}'", text));
         continue; // not number was in listview, continue or break
     }

     if (value <= tenthousand)
     {
          labelVideoViews2.Text = "GREAT";
          labelVideoViews2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
          break;
     }
}
```